# Angular how do I set ip address and port read from a json file as a service for other controllers

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json

I read the ip address and port from a local json file using a service. I obtain this information in my "main" app controller.

## 1. How do I extract the ip address and port and save it in another service, so another controller can use it without having to read the configuration file again? Note: There is no html. I don't want to expose this info on a UI.

## 2. In the code below the json data is returned from the getConfig call in service but the $scope.restIpAddr and $scope.cfg are both printed as undefined in the console log.

```js
// service
angular.module('RDash')
     .service('configService', ['$http', function ($http) {
        var url = 'config.json';
        this.getConfig = function () {
            return $http.get(url).then(function(response) {
                return response.data;
            });
        };
}]);

//main controller
function MasterCtrl($scope, configService, $cookieStore) {

    $scope.restIpAddr = null;
    $scope.restPort = null;
    
    configService.getConfig().then(function (data) {
        $scope.cfg = data;
        $scope.restIpAddr = $scope.cfg.restIpAddr;
        console.log('MasterCtrl - getConfig - data: ', $scope.cfg);
        console.log('MasterCtrl - getConfig - restIpAddr: ', $scope.restIpAddr);
        }, function (error) {
            $scope.status = 'MasterCtrl - getConfig - Unable to load configuration data: ' + error.message;
        });
    
    console.log('MasterCtrl - getConfig - config: ', $scope.cfg);
    
    // snip
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why don't you try to set up a 'config' value?

```
    angular.module('main').value('config', {
        port : '',
        ip : ''
    });
```

And then setting those values in your main module run function...

```
angular.module('main').run(['config', 'configService', function (config, configService) {
    configService.getConfig().then(function (response) {
        //Just in case that wasn't parsed before
        var dataObject = JSON.parse(response.data); 
        config.port = dataObject.restPort;
        config.ip = dataObject.restIpAddr;
    }, function (errorResponse) {
        //Handle error
    });
}]);
```

Then you can inject the 'config' value to the Service or Controller that you need and then accessing to the value .

Hope it helps.